# How do I make Docker run as root?

Tags: docker, root

I created a Docker env to run and now when I run

```
docker run <name> <arguments>
```

it starts off with

```
iptables v1.6.0: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

This needs administrative access to its system, so how do I make Docker run run as root?

Comment: You could use `sudo` on Linux but your question is **off-topic** on StackOverflow. Could fit into https://superuser.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry I should add, the root required message happens when running as user or as root.

Comment: That should go into the question, which remains off-topic here

Comment: See the docs: [Post-installation steps for Linux](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo docker run <name> <arguments>
```

Or, if ypu won't use `sudo` add docker to user group, smtng like that:

```
sudo groupadd docker
```

And `sudo gpasswd -a $USER docker`, after that you should to logout/login.

Or, maybe it's more simple, but I didn't use it:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```